# How can I reinstall dnsmasq?

Tags: network-manager, configuration, dnsmasq

I accidentally removed dnsmasq from my computer by running

```
rm /etc/init.d/dnsmasq
```

I was working in root when I did it. I was trying to learn how to stop DHCP and just messed up. (Now I can't connect to some routers I want to configure over ethernet.)

Anyway, is there a way I can reinstall it? I read [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218655) that it comes with the network manager. Does that mean I need to reinstall the entire network manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this to reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dnsmasq
```